# mysql pdo update record using LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql-update, left-join

```
"UPDATE tablename1  AS t1 LEFT JOIN
tablename2 AS t2 ON t1.pin = t2.pin AND t1.status = t2.status LEFT JOIN
tablename3 AS t3 ON t1.pin = t3.pin AND t1.status = t3.status LEFT JOIN
tablename4 AS t4 ON t1.pin = t4.pin AND t1.status = t4.status LEFT JOIN
tablename5 AS t5 ON t1.pin = t6.pin AND t1.status = t6.status LEFT JOIN
tablename6 AS t6 ON t1.pin = t6.pin AND t1.status = t6.status LEFT JOIN
SET t1.status = : status,
    t2.status = : status,
    t3.status = : status,
    t4.status = : status,
    t5.status = : status,
    t6.status = : status
WHERE t1.pin = : pin
AND t1.status = : active "
```

This is my query for updating multiple tables at the same time. Some of the tables might be empty so I used `LEFT JOIN` so that i only update table with values. But i got this error `near 'SET t1.status = 'NotActive' AND t2.status = 'N' at line 7'` so what i did is to change `,` to `AND` i still get error and when i search for the error `Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]` most of the things i found is this appears when there is a `reserved word`. As far as i am concern there is no reserve word in my code.

Any suggestion is appreaciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE tablename1  AS t1 LEFT JOIN
tablename2 AS t2 ON t1.pin = t2.pin AND t1.status = t2.status LEFT JOIN
tablename3 AS t3 ON t1.pin = t3.pin AND t1.status = t3.status LEFT JOIN
tablename4 AS t4 ON t1.pin = t4.pin AND t1.status = t4.status LEFT JOIN
tablename5 AS t5 ON t1.pin = t6.pin AND t1.status = t6.status LEFT JOIN
tablename6 AS t6 ON t1.pin = t6.pin AND t1.status = t6.status LEFT JOIN ????
SET t1.status = : status,
    t2.status = : status,
    t3.status = : status,
    t4.status = : status,
    t5.status = : status,
    t6.status = : status
WHERE t1.pin = : pin
AND t1.status = : active
```

What is that last LEFT JOIN ???? Is it left joining on the SET part ?

I think you also have a typo on this line:

```
tablename5 AS t5 ON t1.pin = t6.pin AND t1.status = t6.status LEFT JOIN
```

### I think you mean something closer to this:

```
UPDATE tablename1  AS t1
LEFT JOIN tablename2 AS t2 ON t1.pin = t2.pin AND t1.status = t2.status 
LEFT JOIN tablename3 AS t3 ON t1.pin = t3.pin AND t1.status = t3.status 
LEFT JOIN tablename4 AS t4 ON t1.pin = t4.pin AND t1.status = t4.status 
LEFT JOIN tablename5 AS t5 ON t1.pin = t5.pin AND t1.status = t5.status 
LEFT JOIN tablename6 AS t6 ON t1.pin = t6.pin AND t1.status = t6.status
SET t1.status = : status,
    t2.status = : status,
    t3.status = : status,
    t4.status = : status,
    t5.status = : status,
    t6.status = : status
WHERE t1.pin = : pin
AND t1.status = : active
```

Comment: I got confuse with nickname i wasnt aware of the wrong naming plus the excess LEFT JOIN that was so simply yet i missed it thanks for clarification